# How to dial number with special characters using intent Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying the below code to dial a number, but it always dail as *111

```
  Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
  callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*111#"));
  startActivity(callIntent);
```

Please help i am trying to learn android..

Thanks friends..

Comment: FWIW, `#` is a reserved character in URI syntax, so that may be your difficulty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+ Uri.encode("*111#")));
startActivity(callIntent );
```

Happy Coding :)